# How to launch preexisting app with actual device with appium by ruby code

Tags: android, ruby, appium

Could anyone help me actually launch a existing application with appium?

I'm really new to it so actual code would really help.

how would I initialize my caps and do I need the appPackage and appActivity ?? and if so where would I get these values.

Also the last command to actually run the android driver.
thx
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want launch a existing application with appium, you can just hide configuration "app" in your caps. Like this:

```
apk = { 
        platformName: 'android',
        deviceName: "Name",
        appPackage: 'com.android.package',
        appActivity: '.SettingsActivity',
        appWaitActivity: '.SettingsActivity'
      }
Appium::Driver.new({caps: apk}, false).start_driver
```

You can get the package information using the aapt. Like this:

```
aapt dump badging <path-to-apk>
```

For more about appium_lib you can see this link: https://github.com/appium/ruby_lib/tree/master/docs

Sorry for my english. I'm initial level in English language.